# Set variable to conditional value in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to define a variable to be used as a docker buildarg, but I can't make it work:

```yaml
variables:
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/rc/') }}:
    angularenv: 'staging'
  ${{ elseif startsWith(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/rel/') }}:
    angularenv: 'prod'
  ${{ else }}:
    angularenv: 'default'
```

However I'm suspecting something else is off, since I can't make this work:

```yaml
variables:
  temp1: $[replace(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')]
  dockertag: $[replace(variables['temp1'], '/', '')]
  angularenv: 'dev'
```

Since the agent job parameters then only show:

```
Job preparation parameters
Variables:
  temp1:
    Parsing expression: <replace(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')>
    Evaluating: replace(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')
    Expanded: replace('refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/', '')
    Result: 'master'
  dockertag:
    Parsing expression: <replace(variables['temp1'], '/', '')>
    Evaluating: replace(variables['temp1'], '/', '')
    Expanded: replace('master', '/', '')
    Result: 'master'
ContinueOnError: False
```

So basically I can't even set the angularenv to a static value?
What am I missing here?
I'm committing the azure-pipeline.yml to master for now to keep things simple..

I'd be thankful for any cluepons..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define the variables in your YAML file like as below.

```yaml
variables:
- name: angularenv
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/rc/') }}:
    value: 'staging'
  ${{ elseif startsWith(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/rel/') }}:
    value: 'prod'
  ${{ else }}:
    value: 'default'

- name: temp1
  value: ${{ replace(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/', '') }}

- name: dockertag
  value: ${{ replace(variables['temp1'], '/', '') }}
```

I have tested this, it can work as expected.

**Results:**

[image]